# Windows Batch variables available outside a script

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

I'm creating a script that is to create a variable called http_proxy. The script does a bit more than just set the proxy, it has a few statements in there as well as a prompt for user password on load.

I have set up a shortcut to cmd.exe with an extra parameter `/k ".set_http_proxy.bat"` to run on startup, which sets this variable.

Once the script exits, the command prompt remains open for the user to run their scripts. My problem is, the variable http_proxy has vanished now and no trace that it was set in the script that just ran.

Is there a way to set a variable that will remain in use for that session until the command prompt window is closed? I think in `bash` we just use `export` which is great!

current code is simply...

`set http_proxy=http://proxy.address`

Comment: `/k ".set_http_proxy.bat"`? What's the starting dot for? Remove it. I'd expect an errormessage like `'.set_http_porxe.bat' is not recognized ...`

Comment: @Stephan, the file name can start with a dot.

Comment: @Stephan Filenames can start with a dot, its just from my days of bash scripting to make the file hidden. Obviously not the same in Windows, but I try to keep to the same format if possible so I have a generic template.

Comment: @Stephan, Windows only looks at the last file extension to determine file type.

Comment: So there really *is* a dot? Didn't expect that. Is it executed (are you in the correct working folder)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's all, then it should work exactly as you expect, and in fact it did so for me when I tried it out.

Unless you use `setlocal` or launch another process for running a batch file, then environment variables persist even after the batch file finishes.

Comment: What a dummy I am, I had `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top of my script. Removing that seems to have cured it. Thanks Joey

Comment: @RichardC: If you need `setlocal` (although you can set delayed expansion also via a command-line parameter to `cmd`), you can always do an `endlocal & set http_proxy=%http_proxy%` at the end of the batch file to “export” the variable.